# Trying Network Manager's replacement ConnMan

Tags: 10.10, networking, network-manager

I'm aware that Network Manager is going to be replaced by ConnMan. How can I try it out?

**EDIT** I installed `indicator-network` and it's dependencies, so how do use it? Oh, and I'm on 10.10's Unity.

**EDIT** Got it to work with a reboot.

Comment: which version(of ubuntu) are you using?

Comment: @Alaukik, 10.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking of [ConnMan](http://connman.net/). For those that don't know, it was created by Intel and Nokia for Moblin and then Meego. My understanding was it provides slightly fewer options and at slightly better performance.

However, I can't see any plans for Ubuntu to replace Network Manager with it. There's [another AU thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10272/will-connman-replace-networkmanager-on-the-desktop-for-11-04) that essentially says the same thing.

The only changes that really need* to happen are to pull the network manager applet into the new Indicator Applet framework, which is being done in the `indicator-network` package.

*I starred "need" because none of this needs to happen for any other reason than unifying the "system tray" deployment options on desktops.

Comment: As far as I know, only ConnMan's backend is going to be used or something. If you tried it, what do you think of it?

Comment: Oops, looks like I got it backwards.

Comment: @Oxwivi afaik network manager has been ported to indicator-applet (I'm using it all like now on Maverick), so ConnMan won't be needed for that anymore (it never really was **needed** anyway).

Answer (score 5):

Instructions for trying and testing ConnMan are at this page:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ConnMan