# Why is Ubuntu Natty still using Network Manager instead of ConnMan?

Tags: 11.04, network-manager, connman

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will ConnMan replace NetworkManager on the desktop for 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10272/will-connman-replace-networkmanager-on-the-desktop-for-11-04)

I've been using the new Network Indicator in Natty as installed from the this article:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/indicator-network-is-looking-good-in-natty/

Aside from looking a lot better than the default network selection applet that ships with Natty currently, I've found it's also a lot faster at picking up wireless networks and connecting to them.

I notice that it doesn't have support for more complicated security protocols like WPA2-PSK Enterprise, etc. Is this the reason it's being omitted from Natty?